# How to implement pagination or infinite scroll for two scrollable columns in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I need a quick tip about pagination with infinite scroll. I have two bootstrap columns that will use an ul element to create a scroll list that is loaded from database. I want to implement a lazy load with infinite scroll to avoid that the electron vue app can have performance issues. I've writed this pseudo code in a vue method but I'm not sure how to split the two arrays that I have and that will be looped using `v-if`

```js
        paginateDatasets( col ) {
            //
            if( !this.store.supplierFound || !this.store.clientFound ){
                switch( col ) {
                    case 'suppliers':
                        //console.dir( this.$refs.listedSupplier )
                        //scroll top per 50 referenze = 3651.199951171875 px
                        //console.dir( this.$refs.listColSuppliers.scrollTop )
                        //console.dir( this.$refs.listColSuppliers.scrollHeight )
                        let diff = this.$refs.listColSuppliers.scrollHeight - Number(this.$refs.listColSuppliers.scrollTop) 
                        //
                        let clientHeight = this.$refs.listColSuppliers.clientHeight
                        
                        console.log( Number(diff) )
                        if( Number( diff ) === 555 ){
                            //this.
                            console.log('Last index')
                            console.dir( this.$refs.listedSupplier.dataset.index )
                            console.log('Loading more results')
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'clients':
                        console.dir( this.$refs.listedClient )       
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

One array will hold almost 2000 objects and the second one will hold 58000 objects. My idea is to check when the scroll reach the end of the column that have a fixed height of 74vh while the entire container of the app, indipendently from the app window size will have a fixed height of 100vh.
Any tips or help will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the following code:

```js
<script>
export default {
    name: "VirtualList",
    props: {
        // An array for traversing
        listData: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
            require: true,
        },
        // The height of each of these terms
        itemHeight: {
            type: Number,
            default: 20,
            require: true,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        // The total height of the list
        listHeight() {
            return this.listData.length * this.itemHeight;
        },
        //Number of visible
        visibleCount() {
            return Math.ceil(this.screenHeight / this.itemHeight);
        },
        // offset
        getTransform() {
            return `translate3d(0,${this.startOffset}px,0)`;
        },
        // The actual rendered dom
        visibleData() {
            return this.listData.slice(
                    this.start,
                    Math.min(this.end, this.listData.length)
            );
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.screenHeight = this.$el.clientHeight;
        this.start = 0;
        this.end = this.start + this.visibleCount;
    },
    data() {
        return {
            // Visible area height
            screenHeight: 0,
            // offset
            startOffset: 0,
            // Index of the first item in the visual area
            start: 0,
            // The index of the last item in the viewable area
            end: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        scrollEvent() {
            // Gets the current scrollTop
            let scrollTop = this.$refs.list.scrollTop;
            // Computed index
            this.start = Math.floor(scrollTop / this.itemHeight);
            // Computed index
            this.end = this.start + this.visibleCount;
            // Computed offset
            this.startOffset = scrollTop - (scrollTop % this.itemHeight);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.infinite-list-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.infinite-list-phantom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.infinite-list {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
    <div ref="list" class="infinite-list-container" @scroll="scrollEvent($event)">
        <div
                class="infinite-list-phantom"
                :style="{ height: listHeight + 'px' }"
        ></div>
        <div class="infinite-list" :style="{ transform: getTransform }">
            <slot v-for="data in visibleData" :data="data"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This code implements a Virtual List component that has the following features and implementation principles:

1. Features:

- It displays a large amount of data within a limited visible area based on the provided list data (listData) and item height (itemHeight).
- It implements virtual scrolling technique by rendering only the visible items in the viewport, instead of rendering all items at once, to improve performance and reduce memory consumption.

2. Implementation principles:

- In the template section, a container element wraps the list content, and it is referenced using the `ref` attribute.
- Two child elements are used to achieve the scrolling container effect:
- `. infinite-list-phantom`: A placeholder element with a height equal to the entire list, ensuring the correct scrolling range of the container.
- `. infinite-list`: Contains the visible data items, and the scrolling effect is achieved by applying the CSS `transform` property with the offset calculated using `getTransform`.
- Slots are used to render the visible data items.
- Computed properties are used to dynamically calculate the total height of the list (listHeight), the number of visible list items (visibleCount), the style for the offset (getTransform), and the actual visible list data (visibleData).
- In the `mounted` hook of the component, the visible height of the container element is obtained, and the start index (start) and end index (end) are initialized.
- The scroll event (@scroll) is listened to, and based on the calculated scroll position (scrollTop) and item height (itemHeight), the start index, end index, and offset are updated to update the displayed data and adjust the position during scrolling.

With the above implementation, this code can efficiently render a large amount of data by only rendering the currently visible items, achieving a high-performance virtual scrolling list effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can you translate the comments in english please and explain better what the code do?

Comment: @ICTDEV It has been updated

Comment: I will give a try to your solution. I need to implement this with the current bootstrap 5 css implementation. I'll let you know. At the moment the electron app will suffer performance issues because of the big amount of elements to render. I'm looking to this or pagination and I will test both solutions. Thank you